# Database: Currencies By CountryCode?

Tags: c#, database, csv, lookup-tables, country-codes

Where do I get a list of currencies along with country code?

Example

```
Code,    Currency Name,  Country,    Format,     Decimal Points,     Currency Regime,    Major Unit,     Minor Unit,     Equivalence,
USD,    US Dollar,  United States,  $#,###.##,  2,  float,  dollar, cents,  100 cents = dollar
```

REF: http://www.oanda.com/currency/currency-code?srccont=rightnav

<--- this is perfect, however they do not supply a database to download?

Comment: I found this, but it does not contain countrycode http://www.exchange-rate.com/currency-list.html

Comment: Click "Register" on that web page.  This is the way they keep the lights on of course.

Comment: Do you want machine-readable data or any old format like in Wikipedia?

Answer (score 4):

From **Wikipedia**: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_circulating_currencies

Data from **ISO**:
[ISO 4217 currency and funds name and code elements](http://www.iso.org/iso/home/store/catalogue_tc/catalogue_detail.htm?csnumber=46121) 
With the data in [XLS](http://www.currency-iso.org/dl_iso_table_a1.xls) and [XML](http://www.currency-iso.org/dl_iso_table_a1.xml) format.

Comment: This site seems to have moved. [Site](http://www.currency-iso.org/en/home/tables/table-a1.html), [XLS](http://www.currency-iso.org/dam/downloads/dl_iso_table_a1.xls) [XML](http://www.currency-iso.org/dam/downloads/dl_iso_table_a1.xml)

Answer (score 3):

You can get a list of country codes to currency codes from http://country.io/currency.json. Here's a sample extract:

```
...
"US": "USD",
"UY": "UYU",
"UZ": "UZS",
"VA": "EUR",
"VC": "XCD",
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Calling the web services provided here: http://www.webservicex.net/country.asmx you should be able to generate the list you want.

Comment: Yes this site has many mappings but oddly not country code -> currency code! You can pass in a country name, or get the entire list: `http://www.webservicex.net/country.asmx/GetCurrencyCode`

Comment: In fact the URL I gave has very old superseded codes for the currencies of at least Mexico, Romania, and Turkey!

Answer (score 0):

Look this ;)
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_4217

Answer (score 0):

Without a database, you can find those info in System.Globalization

Take a look at this sample:
https://rextester.com/OEPYQ59630